# Rails' guides on Active Recored CUD

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails' official site has good [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/) on Active Record migrations, validations, associations and query (Read), but I could not find guides on C(Create), U(Update), D(Delete). Am I missing anything? Does the author think that beginners should figure these out from API docs?

Answer (score 0):

Look into scaffolding. Try this as a start:

```
$ rails g scaffold Foo bar:string
```

See what files are generated and how they work.